# Usando métodos síncronos juntamente com assíncronos

Tags: c#, async

Por motivos de desenvolvimento, precisei criar uma chamada a um método assíncrono em um método síncrono, porém ao publicar o meu projeto no servidor, o mesmo fica por tempo indeterminado em execução.

Método assíncrono

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryProfileAsync<T>(this DbConnection cnn, string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = default(int?), CommandType? commandType = default(CommandType?))
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
    {
        using (var profiled = new ProfiledDbConnection(cnn, MiniProfiler.Start()))
        {
            return await profiled.QueryAsync<T>(sql, param, transaction, commandTimeout, commandType);
        }
    }
    else return await cnn.QueryAsync<T>(sql, param, transaction, commandTimeout, commandType);
}
```

Método síncrono

```
public static IEnumerable<T> QueryProfile<T>(this DbConnection cnn, string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = default(int?), CommandType? commandType = default(CommandType?))
{
    return QueryProfileAsync<T>(cnn, sql, param, transaction, commandTimeout, commandType).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Em modo de *debug* pelo Visual Studio tudo funciona perfeitamente. A solução foi tirar a chamada ao método assíncrono e executar as mesmas operações, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> QueryProfile<T>(this DbConnection cnn, string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = default(int?), CommandType? commandType = default(CommandType?))
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
    {
        using (var profiled = new ProfiledDbConnection(cnn, MiniProfiler.Start()))
        {
            return profiled.Query<T>(sql, param, transaction);
        }
    }
    else return cnn.Query<T>(sql, param, transaction);
}
```

A grande questão é: Existiria uma forma de realizar uma chamada a um método assíncrono em um método síncrono?

A necessidade de ter métodos síncronos acontece pelo fato de não ser possível fazer uma chamada a uma *Action* assíncrono usando o `Html.Action`.

Comment: Está usando Dapper?

Comment: Sim, mas acredito não ser o Dapper, pois tive o mesmo problema em outro caso semelhante com um SaveChangesAsync do EntityFramework

Comment: Não era mesmo para saber o que está utilizando. Eu tenho projeto todo com Async e não tenho problema, por isso da dúvida...

Comment: O grande problema de eu ter que estar escrevendo métodos não assíncronos é que quando precisar de um `Html.Action` não funciona com Actions async http://stackoverflow.com/a/33915173/2221388

Comment: Hum entendi agora, faltou talvez dizer isso na sua pergunta. Realmente não funciona. Só na versão mais nova ... kkkk ai funciona

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que esteja ocorrendo um deadlock, tente modificar esse seu método `QueryProfileAsync` para utilizar `ConfigureAwait(false)`, dessa forma:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryProfileAsync<T>(this DbConnection cnn, string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = default(int?), CommandType? commandType = default(CommandType?))
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
    {
        using (var profiled = new ProfiledDbConnection(cnn, MiniProfiler.Start()))
        {
            return await profiled.QueryAsync<T>(sql, param, transaction, commandTimeout, commandType).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    else return await cnn.QueryAsync<T>(sql, param, transaction, commandTimeout, commandType).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Sempre que você utilizar o `await` para aguardar a execução de um método assíncrono dentro de outro método assíncrono, utilize o `ConfigureAwait(false)`, a menos que você precise de fato continuar a execução do método dentro do contexto de sincronização da aplicação que você estiver executando.

O deadlock pode ocorrer pelo seguinte motivo:

1. Um método síncrono faz uma chamada sincronamente a um método assíncrono, assim **bloqueando** o contexto de sincronização, enquanto aguarda o método assíncrono terminar
2. O método assíncrono, faz uma chamada a outro método assíncrono com **await** (no teu caso o `await profiled.QueryAsync<T>`) sem o `ConfigureAwait(false)`
3. Quando o método `profiled.QueryAsync<T>` termina, o método `QueryProfileAsync` tentará continuar sua execução dentro do contexto de sincronização (devido a não utilização do `ConfigureAwait(false)`), mas não conseguirá pois o método síncrono está com o mesmo bloqueado.
4. O método assíncrono ficará bloqueado aguardando o contexto de sincronização ficar disponível, mas isso nunca ocorrerá, pois o método síncrono ficará indefinidamente aguardando a finalização do método assíncrono.

> Recomendo a leitura dessa [publicação no blog do Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) para um entendimento mais detalhado de como tudo isso funciona.